# Webcenter Capture 12c Commit Exception

Tags: capture, webcenter

After I hit the Release button in Webcenter Capture I am getting the following error in the logs:

Why am I getting this error?

```
[2018-01-23T19:58:50.189+04:00] [capture_server2] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.odc.commitprocessor.CommitProcessor] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '32' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: anonymous] [ecid: 005OrEVNDRt8hoKayTnZ6G000157002GRr,1:1] [APP: capture] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  [Ar_6 (3621)] Loading Capture metadata definitions from workspace ID 27.
[2018-01-23T19:58:50.240+04:00] [capture_server2] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.odc.commitprocessor.CommitProcessor] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '32' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: anonymous] [ecid: 005OrEVNDRt8hoKayTnZ6G000157002GRr,1:1] [APP: capture] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  [Ar_6 (3621)] Initializing RIDC.
[2018-01-23T19:58:50.377+04:00] [capture_server2] [ERROR] [] [oracle.odc.commitprocessor.CommitProcessor] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '32' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: anonymous] [ecid: 005OrEVNDRt8hoKayTnZ6G000157002GRr,1:1] [APP: capture] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  [Ar_6 (3621)] OCR2FILE failed with error (4).
[2018-01-23T19:58:50.407+04:00] [capture_server2] [ERROR] [] [oracle.odc.commitprocessor.CommitProcessor] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '32' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: anonymous] [ecid: 005OrEVNDRt8hoKayTnZ6G000157002GRr,1:1] [APP: capture] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  [Ar_6 (3621)] OCR2FILE failed with error (4).
[2018-01-23T19:58:50.436+04:00] [capture_server2] [ERROR] [] [oracle.odc.commitprocessor.CommitProcessor] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '32' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: anonymous] [ecid: 005OrEVNDRt8hoKayTnZ6G000157002GRr,1:1] [APP: capture] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  [Ar_6 (3621)] OCR2FILE failed with error (4).
[2018-01-23T19:58:50.465+04:00] [capture_server2] [ERROR] [] [oracle.odc.commitprocessor.CommitProcessor] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '32' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: anonymous] [ecid: 005OrEVNDRt8hoKayTnZ6G000157002GRr,1:1] [APP: capture] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  [Ar_6 (3621)] OCR2FILE failed with error (4).
[2018-01-23T19:58:50.482+04:00] [capture_server2] [WARNING] [] [oracle.odc.commitprocessor.CommitProcessor] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '32' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: anonymous] [ecid: 005OrEVNDRt8hoKayTnZ6G000157002GRr,1:1] [APP: capture] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] OCR2FILE failed with error (4).[[
oracle.odc.exception.CommitException: OCR2FILE failed with error (4).
        at oracle.odc.export.PDFSearchable.exportDocument(PDFSearchable.java:186)
        at oracle.odc.commitprocessor.CommitProcessor.processBatch(CommitProcessor.java:493)
        at oracle.odc.batchprocessor.BatchProcessorBean.processMessage(BatchProcessorBean.java:135)
        at oracle.odc.batchprocessor.CommitProcessorBean.onMessage(CommitProcessorBean.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:101)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor348.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:94)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.ejb.JpsAbsInterceptor$1.run(JpsAbsInterceptor.java:131)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.ejb.JpsAbsInterceptor.runJaasMode(JpsAbsInterceptor.java:118)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.ejb.JpsAbsInterceptor.intercept(JpsAbsInterceptor.java:197)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.ejb.JpsInterceptor.intercept(JpsInterceptor.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor365.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:94)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy320.onMessage(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:438)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:361)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:297)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:5107)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4775)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:4170)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:127)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5627)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)

]]
[2018-01-23T19:58:50.639+04:00] [capture_server2] [WARNING] [] [oracle.odc.batchprocessor.BatchProcessorBean] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '32' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: anonymous] [ecid: 005OrEVNDRt8hoKayTnZ6G000157002GRr,1:1] [APP: capture] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] oracle.odc.exception.CommitException: An error occurred during commit process.
[2018-01-23T19:58:50.647+04:00] [capture_server2] [WARNING] [] [oracle.odc.batchprocessor.BatchProcessorBean] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '32' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: anonymous] [ecid: 005OrEVNDRt8hoKayTnZ6G000157002GRr,1:1] [APP: capture] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  [Ar_6 (3621)] Throwing EJBException so the batch processing will be reattempted.
[2018-01-23T19:58:50.648+04:00] [capture_server2] [ERROR] [] [oracle.odc.batchprocessor.BatchProcessorBean] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '32' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: anonymous] [ecid: 005OrEVNDRt8hoKayTnZ6G000157002GRr,1:1] [APP: capture] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  [Ar_6 (3621)] javax.ejb.EJBException: oracle.odc.exception.CommitException: An error occurred during commit process.
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause: The LD_LIBRARY_PATH was not set correctly.

Specific libraries were shown as "not found".

Solution:
To correct the problem any of the following that's needed:

Update setDomainEnv.sh with the correct LD_LIBARY_PATH to the contentaccess folder.
Restart the system.
Example path: .../.../.../Oracle_ECM1/oit/linux64/lib/contentaccess

The path can also be added to the bottom of the setDomainEnv.sh file, saved, and a restart of the servers to set.

DISPLAY=:1
export DISPLAY
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/Middleware/oit/linux64/lib/contentaccess
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH